# What do you do with a commit that was rejected in a pull request?

Tags: git, github

My pull request on Github was declined. I am not quite sure what to do, as I am still new. Should I delete my commit and reset my branch? Or should I simply fix my commit error, and do another pull request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make the changes in new commits on your branch or fork (depending on whichever you've used), push the commits to the remote branch or fork and they'll update the pull request automatically. Then let people know you've updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd fix the very commit using `git commit --amend` and force push with `git push -f`. I don't like when a pull request piles fixes upon fixes. Even less squash merges.

Comment: `git push -f` needs to be used with extreme caution (as it rewrites history). Would you consider it safe for a beginner?

Comment: For a beginner I'd recommend [`git push --force-with-lease`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---no-force-with-lease).